# Java TimerTask not canceling

Tags: java, timer, timertask

My CheckStatus (TimerTask) is not stopping when I call cancel() inside the run method.  this.cancel() also does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
class CheckStatus extends TimerTask {
   int s = 3;
   public void run() {
      if (s > 0)
      {
         System.out.println("checking status");
         s--;
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("cancel");
         cancel();
      }
   }
}
```

Heres my driver

```
import java.util.*;
class Game {
   static Timer timer;
   static CheckStatus status;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
      CheckStatus status = new CheckStatus();
      timer = new Timer();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(status, 0, 3000);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me - using exactly the code you posted, I saw:

```
checking status
checking status
checking status
cancel
```

... and nothing else, showing that the `TimerTask` has been cancelled - it's never executing again.

Were you expecting the `Timer` itself to shut down when it didn't have any more work to do? It doesn't do that automatically. It's not clear what your bigger goal is, but one option to avoid this is to make the `TimerTask` also cancel the `Timer` - that will work, but it's not terribly nice in terms of design, and means that the `TimerTask` can't run nicely within a timer which contains other tasks.

Comment: @Raptrex: But the `Timer` *isn't* done - it's still available, it's just that nothing scheduled in it. As far as the JVM is aware, something else could add another task to it. Now you could make it run in daemon threads (pass `true` to the `Timer` constructor) but then of course you'd need to keep the main thread alive until your task had cancelled itself. Assuming this is part of a larger program, it's hard to know how to advise you without knowing more context.

Answer (score 2):

you are calling the cancel method of the timer task but you should call the cancel method of the timer itself to get your expected behaviour.